# Show change log of other branch with vc-git

Tags: git, vc

When using VC for a Git repository on Emacs 24.3, I want to view commits in a different branch from the one I've checked out.

It seems like `C-u C-x v l` should be command for that, as it asks `Log from revision (default: last revision):`, but if I enter `origin/master`, the `*vc-change-log*` buffer still shows the revision history of the currently checked out branch, just as if I had used plain `C-x v l`.

Is there a way to get VC to show the change log for a different branch, or do I need to stick with `M-! git log HEAD..origin/master`?

Comment: Thank you for the retrospective bounty, legoscia. Very nice of you, and I'm glad you found the answer so useful.

Comment: Yes, I use your function at least once a week. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to be calling `vc-print-log-internal` with the `IS-START-REVISION` argument. e.g.:

```el
(vc-print-log-internal 'Git '("/var/www/CHANGELOG.txt") "origin/master" t 2000)
```

You could make a modified variant of `vc-print-log` to provide a command to do this, if there's nothing which does this already? (and I'm not seeing anything myself).

```el
(defun my-vc-print-revision-log (working-revision &optional limit)
  "List the change log at WORKING-REVISION of the current fileset in a window.

If LIMIT is non-nil, it should be a number specifying the maximum
number of revisions to show; the default is `vc-log-show-limit'.

When called interactively with a prefix argument, prompts for LIMIT also."
  (interactive
   (let ((rev (read-from-minibuffer
               "Working revision (default: last revision): " nil nil nil nil))
         (lim (when current-prefix-arg
                (string-to-number (read-from-minibuffer
                                   "Limit display (unlimited: 0): "
                                   (format "%s" vc-log-show-limit)
                                   nil nil nil)))))
     (when (string= rev "") (setq rev nil))
     (when (and lim (<= lim 0)) (setq lim nil))
     (list rev lim)))
  (let* ((vc-fileset (vc-deduce-fileset t)) ;FIXME: Why t? --Stef
         (backend (car vc-fileset))
         (files (cadr vc-fileset)))
    (vc-print-log-internal backend files working-revision t limit)))
```

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` perhaps? I'd think this would be a useful addition, despite not all backends supporting the argument in question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for VC, but for magit, there is magit-log-ranged which should do what you want.

Comment: Since `v2.1` that  is no longer the case. Now a multi-line log is automatically used when an argument is used that requires that (`--path`, `--stat`, and/or `++header`).